# Do I need a transit visa to pass through Australia?

Tags: visas, international-travel, australia, us-citizens, transit-visas

I booked a cheap (nightmare) ticket from Wellington NZ to Kathmandu via Sydney and KL. I am a US citizen and New Zealand resident; my wife is a dual US and Australian citizen. We have to pick up our bags after every flight and re-check them in. The holdover in Sydney is just about 4 hours a bit over.

Will I need a visa to go and get my bags and then re-enter the terminal for my next flight? The first airline is Air New Zealand, the next is Air Asia. I know I will not need a visa for KL as we get it on arrival and same in Kathmandu, but Australia is somewhat complicated. Should I apply for an online electronic travel visa?

Comment: Is this a single, through-ticket?

Answer (score 5):

**No**, neither of you needs a transit visa for Australia, as long as it's under 72h.

Quoting the Australian [border](http://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia) agency on the matter (emphasis mine):

> The following categories of travellers are eligible to transit through
> Australia without applying for a visa:
> Citizens of the following
> countries:
>
> Andorra, Argentina, Austria, Belgium, Brunei, Bulgaria,
> Canada, Chile, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia,
> Federated States of Micronesia, Fiji, Finland, France, Germany,
> Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Indonesia, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Kiribati,
> Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malaysia, Malta,
> Marshall Islands, Mexico, Monaco, Nauru, Netherlands, New Zealand,
> Norway, Oman, Palau, Papua New Guinea, Philippines, Poland, Portugal,
> Qatar, Romania, Samoa, San Marino, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia,
> Solomon Islands, South Africa, South Korea, Spain, Sweden,
> Switzerland, Thailand, Tonga, Tuvalu, United Arab Emirates, United
> Kingdom (including its colonies), **United States of America**,
> Uruguay, Vanuatu and Vatican.

However, as Calchas noted you would need a proper visa if you need to recheck your bags

> If passengers are required to pass through Immigration clearance and
> check-in to their onward flight, including managing their luggage,
> they will require a visa to enter Australia. An appropriate visa for
> this purpose will need to be applied for and granted before travelling
> to Australia.

Comment: But to be clear this provision relates to a straight international-international transit, using the bypass lane that goes back to the international lounge, without passing through the Australian border. If @JaySessa needs to collect and re-check luggage, he may need an e-visa. [Quite who spends 72 hours in a transit lounge is another matter]

Comment: @Calchas quite right, updated. Not sure my answer is more confusing than helpful now

Comment: As far as I know, Americans can just use an ETA and do not need a visa for a landside transit.

Comment: The 72 hour limit and the need for a visa to recheck bags apply only to the OP.  His wife will never need a visa unless she loses her Australian nationality.